# How to parse nested JSON object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm sending the following JSON to Rails 4.1.0

```
Started POST "/orders.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-11 15:19:34 +0200
Processing by OrdersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"order"=>{"name"=>"Jon", "surname"=>"Do", "line_items_attributes"=>[{"work_id"=>16, "quantity"=>1, "total_price"=>34.5}, {"work_id"=>12, "quantity"=>2, "total_price"=>40}]}}
Unpermitted parameters: line_items_attributes
```

but I'm getting Unpermitted parameters error. My Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :dispatch_method
  belongs_to :payment_method
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items 
end
```

My  orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.create(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :surname, line_items_attributes: [:id, :work_id, :quantity, :total_price])
    end
end
```

I'm able to create and save a  new instance of order, but not of a line_item.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to redefine your `order_params` like this:

```
def order_params
  json_params = ActionController::Parameters.new(JSON.parse(params[:order]))
  return json_params.require(:name, :surname).permit(line_items_attributes: [:id, :work_id, :quantity, :total_price])
end
```

As you see, I am parsing `params[:order]` to avoid parsing the full `params` var. You might need to add another json level here but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Getting closer, but not quite there yet. Here is the error I'm getting this time:

    `TypeError (no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String):`

Comment: How embarassing! Seems I was editing a wrong file. When fixed, all works as expected with the above setup.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
render :json => @booking, :include => [:paypal, 
                                       :boat_people,
                                       :boat => {:only => :name, :include => {:port => {:only => :name, :include => {:city => {:only => :name, :include => {:country => {:only => :name}}}}}, 
                                                :boat_model => {:only => :name, :include => {:boat_type => {:only => :name}}}}}]
```